# Manytomany field returns empty list

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

I'm new to django so may not know smth but i've searched through google and haven't got any answer. 
I have such models:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/', blank=True, null=True)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/', blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.word

class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    lesson_words_list = models.ManyToManyField(Word)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

And i have next function in views:

```
def view_lesson(request, language, lesson_title):
    cur_lesson = Lesson.objects.filter(title__iexact = lesson_title).get(language__name__iexact=language)
    words_list = cur_lesson.lesson_words_list.all()
    return render_to_response("view_lesson.html", {"language":language, "lesson_title": lesson_title, "words_list":words_list})
```

here is how i call it in the template:

```
{% for Word in words_list %}        
{{ Word.word }}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is words_list is empty while through the admin i clearly see that my lesson has related words.
Why could it be empty? and where should i search for an answer?

Comment: how are you showing the word lists in the template? Also, you're query should be Lesson.objects.get(title__iexact = lesson_title, language__name__iexact=language). There's no point filtering, and then get'ing

Comment: oh, thnx for the tip i haven't seen that.

Answer (score 2):

Is

```
{{ cur_lesson }}
```

showing the correct lesson in your template?

Try:

```
{% for word in cur_lesson.lesson_word_list.all %}
    {{ word }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also see if

```
{{ cur_lesson.lesson_word_list.all }}
```

show the correct list of words in your template

Comment: i've tried all that but all of it are empty, i only see values - language and lesson_title.
words_list is like []
and the rest is just not showing.

Comment: So you're query is then no getting the correct lesson from the database no? Are you sure the query and your URLs are correct? i.e. the view is getting the correct 'language' & 'lesson_title' values?

Comment: yeah, it's seems so, and i don't get why it's like that.
URLs seems to be correct coz it's renders okay, and yeah i have correct 'language' & 'lesson_title' values, at least when they're shown in my template they're okay.

Comment: btw if it could help, when i've tried to run in shell, and set values for example language='polish',lesson_title='test_pol'(the ones i see through admin) it tells me there is no matching but it does find match for title only. and when i get object and put it's value of language instead of language it also works. i just dunno why it's like that. everything before that works fine but i really need to get this words_list.

Comment: Thnx for attention, it was problem with data in db.